# Which companies use personal data

Tags: internet, data-ownership, data-protection

I am not an expert in Law and I apologize if I make a big mistake by choosing wrong words.

Since there are lots of new laws about data protection being enforced by courts, it became easier to see if a technological company processes personal data. Is there an easy way for me to find the companies which use personal data? I am looking for the companies which are in the internet&technology sectors.

I am trying [HUDOC](https://hudoc.echr.coe.int/eng#%7B%22documentcollectionid2%22:[%22GRANDCHAMBER%22,%22CHAMBER%22]%7D) for example. But there is no such tags for me to find these easily.

Comment: "personal data" is pretty broad in what it covers. Can you add an example of what you are trying to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the US we have the wall of shame. It’s a report of health care data breaches and is mandated by legislation.

https://ocrportal.hhs.gov/ocr/breach/breach_report.jsf

I know this isn’t a complete answer, but I’m not sure there is a complete answer to this question.

Comment: It asks for companies which use (or process, though they're equivalent in context) personal data. Not this which have failed to protect the personal data they possess, but *all* companies that *use* personal data. That this answer was accepted shows how vague the question was, to the point it asks something the user didn't even apparently want.

Comment: @Nij OP commented on Dale M’s answer which clarified the question.

Comment: No, they asked a separate follow-up question in a comment. So that's neither part of this question nor relevant to answering it.

Comment: @Nij would you like me to delete the answer? I’ll do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Every company uses personal data.

At the least, they keep the names and contact details of their officers, employees, customers and suppliers.

Comment: And which do use data in a problematic way?